# Did not understand how i received the numbers in output?

Tags: c

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main() {
    int x = 3;
    while (x > 0, x--) {
      printf("positive");
    }
    printf("%d", & x);
    return 0;
  }
```

output - `positivepositivepositive1472586508`
how I got these numbers in output

Comment: In your own words, when you write `printf("%d",&x);`, what do you think the `&` means, and why do you write it?

Comment: What do you want `while (x>0,x--)` to do? First `x>0` is evaluated, then `x` is evaluated and applied to the `while`, then `x` is decremented. Did you mean `while (x-- > 0)`?

Comment: Please choose a title which is useful for others with the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: to tell the compiler address for variable x

Comment: `while (x>0, x--)` is equivalent to `while(x--)` which is equivalent to `while(x-- != 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are trying to do is, printing the value of `x` after some iteration, fixed code is:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
    int x=3;
     while (x>0)
      {     printf("positive");
            x--;
      }
        printf("%d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Note:

1. formatting is important this would help future coders to understand easily.
2. `&` -- denotes the address of any variable, while you printing the value of `x` with the ampersand operator, you actually denotes its address.

Comment: i can't figure out he difference between   `while (x>0)
      {     printf("positive");
            x--;
      }` and  `while (x>0,x--)
      {     printf("positive");
         }`

Comment: @darthray: they are basically the same thing, but it is recommended to use a single statement in a single line. for better understanding of your codes.

Comment: These are **not** the same thing. The comma in the second case is an operator and it means that only the value of the last expression is considered in the evaluation. Since the first expression is a comparison and has no side effects it means just nothing. So the first loop, as wrote by @PapaifromBEKOAIL could be just `while (x--) printf("positive\n");`

Answer (score 0):

You got that number because you were printing memory address of that variable.when `&` used before any variable that represent address of that variable.In case of `printf()` dont use it just use variable name.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int x=3;
 while (x>0,x--)
  {     
      printf("positive");
    }
printf("%d",x);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh thanks got it now

Comment: Note that this loop makes little sense. It is the same as `while (x--) printf("positive\n");` The comma is an operator and the first expression is just discarded, since it does nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
  int main() {
    int x = 3;
    while (x > 0) {
      printf("positive");
      x--;
    }
```

I little bit edit your code but output is same. up to this point output is "positivepositivepositive"
after that you are trying to print memory address of the x variable. that's why output is undefined number. if you use printf statement to print variable value with & sign it always give the memory address of that variable.

```
printf("%d", & x);
```

using & sign this part give memory address of the x variable.

```
printf("%d", x);
```

if you use this without & sign it give the value of x variable. (x=0)

Comment: please note that this loop is the same as `while (x--) printf("positive\n");`  since `0` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The code as it is

```
#include <stdio.h>

  int main() {
    int x = 3;
    while (x > 0, x--) {
      printf("positive");
    }
    printf("%d", & x);
    return 0;
  }
```

is a bit strange:

the expression `x>0, x--` is the same as `x--`

The comma here is an operator, the sequence operator. An here's what it means:

- the first expression is executed `x > 0`, resulting in a number, 0 or 1, and this result is discarded. Since the expression has no other effects it means nothing, but with a delay ;) .
- then the second expression `x--` is evaluated, and its result is used to evaluate the `while` condition. So the `while` will break when `x` is `0` a.k.a. `false` in `C`.
- The expression has a post-decrement operator so it is always executed, leaving `x` as `-1` at the last `printf`

A sequence `e = a,b,c,d;` in C means that all expressions are evaluated, but only the result of the last is considered as the result of the expression

Sure, as noted by others, the `&` is misplaced at the original code.

The code is the same as

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x = 3;
    while (x--) printf("positive\n");
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

that shows

```
positive
positive
positive
-1
```

#### more about sequence operations

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x = 3;
    while (x--) printf("positive\n");
    printf("    [1] %d\n", x);
    x = x>0, x<0, x + 2, x--;
    printf("    [2] %d\n", x);
    x = x>0, x<0, 1;
    printf("    [3]  %d\n", x);
    x = 0, x<0, --x;
    printf("    [4]  %d, ", x);

    if ( x = 0, x<0, x-- )
        printf("true\n");
    else
        printf("false\n");
    printf("    [5]  %d\n", x);

    x = 11,2,3,4,5,6,0;
    printf("    [6]  %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

shows

```
positive
positive
positive
    [1] -1
    [2] -1
    [3]  0
    [4]  -1, false
    [5]  -1
    [6]  11
```

and shows a few cases of the comma operator --- not the same as the comma separator as in arguments or declarations